# Can this function be described by a formula?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, logic, first-order-logic, peano-axioms

Suppose $PA$ is [Peano arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic). For $m \in \mathbb{N}$ define $\overline{m}$ as a term in the language of $PA$ using the following recurrence.

$$\overline{0} = 0$$

$$\overline{m + 1} = S(\overline{m})$$

Now let’s say that $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is *described* by a formula $\phi(x)$ with a single free variable $x$ iff $PA \vdash \forall x (\phi(x) \to (x = \overline{n}))$ and let’s say that a function $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is *described* by a formula $\psi(x, y)$ with exactly two free variables $x$ and $y$ iff $\forall m \in \mathbb{N}$ $PA \vdash \forall x \forall y (((x = \overline{m}) \& \psi(x, y)) \to (y = \overline{f(x)}))$.

Any number is described by some formula (take for example $\phi(x) = ‘x = \overline{n}’$). However, not every function is described by a formula because there are continuum many functions but only countably many formulas.

Let’s define a function $L: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ that maps any natural number $n$ to the minimal possible length (number of symbols in the word) of a formula that describes $n$.

My question is:

> Can $L$ be described by a formula?

Comment: What is the benefit of asking a question and simultaneously answering to its own question ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA When you're posting a question, there is a checkbox marked "Answer your own question – [share your knowledge, Q&A-style](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)". I supppose you can find an answer to your question there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it can not.

Define $\Gamma(n) = \min\{x| L(x) \geq 4n\}$. Then if $L(x)$ is described by a formula $\psi(x, y)$, then $\Gamma$ is described by a formula $$\xi(x, y) = "\forall t ((t < x\times\overline{4}) \to \neg \psi(y, t)) \& \forall z ((z < y) \to \exists d ((d \leq x\times\overline{4}) \& \psi(y, d)))"$$

Now suppose $\lambda$ is the length of $\xi$. From the fact, that $\xi(x, y)$ describes $\Gamma$ it follows, that $\phi(y) = "\forall x ((x = \overline{n}) \to \xi(x, y))"$ describes $\Gamma(n)$. From that we can conclude, that $L(\Gamma(n)) \leq 10 + \lambda + 3n$. But on the other hand, $L(\Gamma(n)) \geq 4n$ by definition. And here we get the contradiction.